# Build Android 5.0 source in mac yosemite

Tags: xcode, android-source

In mac Yosemite, I build android 5.0 source code, but have errors, and my MACSDK is 10.10.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: #error architecture not supported
>    #error architecture not supported
>     ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:0,
>                    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.plaIn file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:0,
>                    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:64,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin.c:30:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:1: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
>    typedef __int64_t __darwin_blkcnt_t; /* total blocks */
>    ^
>   tform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27,
>                    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:64,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/atexit.h:29,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin_so.c:57:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: #error architecture not supported
>    #error architecture not supported
>     ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_blksize_t; /* preferred block size */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdIn file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:0,
>                    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:64,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/atexit.h:29,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin_so.c:57:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:1: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
>    typedef __int64_t __darwin_blkcnt_t; /* total blocks */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_blksize_t; /* preferred block size */
>    ^
>   k/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_dev_t;  /* dev_t */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_dev_t;  /* dev_t */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_gid_t;  /* [???] process and group IDs */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_gid_t;  /* [???] process and group IDs */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_id_t;  /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_id_t;  /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:1: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
>    typedef __uint64_t __darwin_ino64_t; /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:1: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
>    typedef __uint64_t __darwin_ino64_t; /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Develo/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:66:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_ino_t;  /* [???] Used for inodes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
>    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
>    ^
>   per/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:0,
>                    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27,
>                    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:64,
>                    from bionic/libc/include/stdint.h:32,
>                    from bionic/libc/bionic/crtbrand.c:26:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: #error architecture not supported
>    #error architecture not supported
>     ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:1: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'
>    typedef __uint16_t __darwin_mode_t; /* [???] Some file attributes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:66:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_ino_t;  /* [???] Used for inodes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
>    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:1: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
>    typedef __int64_t __darwin_off_t;  /* [???] Used for file sizes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:1: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'
>    typedef __uint16_t __darwin_mode_t; /* [???] Some file attributes */
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:0,
>                    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:64,
>                    from bionic/libc/include/stdint.h:32,
>                    from bionic/libc/bionic/crtbrand.c:26:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSXExport includes file: bionic/libc/Android.mk -- out/target/product/flo/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_freebsd_intermediates/export_includes
>   10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:1: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
>    typedef __int64_t __darwin_blkcnt_t; /* total blocks */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:1: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
>    typedef __int64_t __darwin_off_t;  /* [???] Used for file sizes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_pid_t;  /* [???] process and group IDs */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    type/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_sigset_t; /* [???] signal set */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_suseconds_t; /* [???] microseconds */
>    ^
>   def __int32_t __darwin_pid_t;  /* [???] process and group IDs */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_uid_t;  /* [???] user IDs */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_sigset_t; /* [???] signal set */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_suseconds_t; /* [???] microseconds */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_useconds_t; /* [???] microseconds */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_uid_t;  /* [???] user IDs */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_useconds_t; /* [???] microseconds */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_blksize_t; /* preferred block size */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_dev_t;  /* dev_t */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_gid_t;  /* [???] process and group IDs */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_id_t;  /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:1: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
>    typedef __uint64_t __darwin_ino64_t; /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:66:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_ino_t;  /* [???] Used for inodes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
>    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:1: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'
>    typedef __uint16_t __darwin_mode_t; /* [???] Some file attributes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:1: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
>    typedef __int64_t __darwin_off_t;  /* [???] Used for file sizes */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_pid_t;  /* [???] process and group IDs */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_sigset_t; /* [???] signal set */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:1: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
>    typedef __int32_t __darwin_suseconds_t; /* [???] microseconds */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_uid_t;  /* [???] user IDs */
>    ^
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:1: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
>    typedef __uint32_t __darwin_useconds_t; /* [???] microseconds */
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:69:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin.c:30:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_ptrdiff_t.h:31:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_ptrdiff_t'
>    typedef __darwin_ptrdiff_t ptrdiff_t;
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:69:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/atexit.h:29,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin_so.c:57:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_ptrdiff_t.h:31:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_ptrdiff_t'
>    typedef __darwin_ptrdiff_t ptrdiff_t;
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:69:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/include/stdint.h:32,
>                    from bionic/libc/bionic/crtbrand.c:26:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_ptrdiff_t.h:31:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_ptrdiff_t'
>    typedef __darwin_ptrdiff_t ptrdiff_t;
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:77:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin.c:30:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h:30:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_size_t'
>    typedef __darwin_size_t        size_t; 
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:77:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/include/stdint.h:32,
>                    from bionic/libc/bionic/crtbrand.c:26:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h:30:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_size_t'
>    typedef __darwin_size_t        size_t; 
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:77:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/atexit.h:29,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin_so.c:57:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h:30:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_size_t'
>    typedef __darwin_size_t        size_t; 
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:79:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin.c:30:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_wchar_t.h:33:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wchar_t'
>    typedef __darwin_wchar_t wchar_t;
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:79:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/include/stdint.h:32,
>                    from bionic/libc/bionic/crtbrand.c:26:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_wchar_t.h:33:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wchar_t'
>    typedef __darwin_wchar_t wchar_t;
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:79:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/atexit.h:29,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin_so.c:57:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_wchar_t.h:33:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wchar_t'
>    typedef __darwin_wchar_t wchar_t;
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:82:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/atexit.h:29,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin_so.c:57:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_wint_t.h:31:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wint_t'
>    typedef __darwin_wint_t wint_t;
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:82:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/arch-common/bionic/crtbegin.c:30:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_wint_t.h:31:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wint_t'
>    typedef __darwin_wint_t wint_t;
>    ^
>   In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:82:0,
>                    from bionic/libc/include/stdint.h:32,
>                    from bionic/libc/bionic/crtbrand.c:26:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_wint_t.h:31:1: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wint_t'
>    typedef __darwin_wint_t wint_t;

Comment: make: *** [out/target/product/flo/obj/lib/crtbrand.s] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/target/product/flo/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic1.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/target/product/flo/obj/lib/crtbegin_so.o] Error 1 thats all logs

Comment: is this log from eclipse? or android studio?

Comment: no,it's from console,i build whole android source code,run make in android path

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [HOW To Build CyanogenMod on OSX Yosemite](http://www.droidforums.net/threads/guide-how-to-build-cyanogenmod-on-osx-yosemite.275799/)

The important part is making sure you are using the older version of XCode

Comment: I had these same problems and they were fixed by reverting to the older sdk